# Sqlite high ram usage when connected from other thread

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, memory-consumption

I found a problem with sqlite which I can't solve for few days now. The problem is that when I try to create new database (new connection) from other thread then main (thread which has main method), sqlite will allocate much more memory then usual.

Here is quite simple example what I'm trying to do.

```
https://pastebin.com/BkU3uMCb
```

There are results of memory usage (from proc/pid/status) when database is opened from main thread.

```
VmPeak:    19780 kB
VmSize:    19636 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:      1756 kB
VmRSS:      1756 kB
VmData:      308 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:         8 kB
VmLib:      4744 kB
VmPTE:        60 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

And there are results when sqlite is opened from other thread

```
VmPeak:   158904 kB
VmSize:    93368 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:      1636 kB
VmRSS:      1636 kB
VmData:    74040 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:         8 kB
VmLib:      4744 kB
VmPTE:        60 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

Most notable difference is VmData, which is like 80MB in case when the other thread is started.
Is there any reason, why sqlite consumes so much memory when started from other thread ? Or do I have any error in my application ?

Comment: What happens if your first example also starts a thread (That doesn't do anything, or just sleeps for a while)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I tried it, it starts thread which allocates a little bit memory (1 - 2 MB), but not so much. Then it executes everything, what it has to do.

Comment: I tried it once more, there are results and updated source code. https://pastebin.com/yB24Ngaq

VmData grow up to 8MB.